# How to log SQL with log4jdbc?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, logback, log4jdbc

In a 2.0 Playframework project, I would like to analyze issued SQL queries by [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/). I am using log4jdbc for that but I can't get it to work.

I have added the `log4jdbc.jar` file in `lib/` folder and changed my application.conf file to following :

```
db.default.driver=net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy
db.default.url="jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase"
db.default.user="username"
db.default.pass="password"
```

It is resulting in a `Cannot connect to database [default]` error. Without the log4jdbc, everything works fine. Am I missing something?

Ps : an important notice, I am also using the play-slick extension which seems to be the origin of the problem.

EDIT : By searching a little deeper, the exact error is "No suitable driver found".

Comment: Apparently Play DB Plugin doesn't prevent from using this kind of url. If you look in DB.scala in module play-jdbc Line 345, it just passes the url to JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Play DB Plugin doesn't prevent from using this kind of url. If you look in DB.scala in module play-jdbc Line 345, it just passes the url to JDBC.

```
conf.getString("url") match {
  case Some(PostgresFullUrl(username, password, host, dbname)) =>
    datasource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://%s/%s".format(host, dbname))
    datasource.setUsername(username)
    datasource.setPassword(password)
  case Some(url @ MysqlFullUrl(username, password, host, dbname)) =>
    val defaultProperties = """?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci"""
    val addDefaultPropertiesIfNeeded = MysqlCustomProperties.findFirstMatchIn(url).map(_ => "").getOrElse(defaultProperties)
    datasource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://%s/%s".format(host, dbname + addDefaultPropertiesIfNeeded))
    datasource.setUsername(username)
    datasource.setPassword(password)
  case Some(url @ H2DefaultUrl()) if !url.contains("DB_CLOSE_DELAY") =>
    if (Play.maybeApplication.exists(_.mode == Mode.Dev)) {
      datasource.setJdbcUrl(url + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
    } else {
      datasource.setJdbcUrl(url)
    }
  case Some(s: String) =>
    datasource.setJdbcUrl(s)
  case _ =>
    throw conf.globalError("Missing url configuration for database [%s]".format(conf))
}
```

So the pb might be in the datasource itself (BoneCP)

Comment: You were on the right way. It looks like play-slick is the problem. I am gonna dig a little further.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `logger.com.jolbox.bonecp=DEBUG` and/or `logger.scala.slick=DEBUG` instead? That is usually more than enough logging, just can't seem to get some transaction logging going.

Oh and you need to set `db.default.logStatements=true` for the bonecp logging to work.

Comment: That is indeed the fallback I decided to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `db.default.logStatements=true` in your application.conf? Maybe it's just supported by Anorm?

Comment: I do not use `anorm` but `slick`, another library from Typesafe.